Wiremock standalone change a date
I am using Wiremock from docker compose
wiremock:
    image: "wiremock/wiremock:latest"
    ports:
        - "8095:8080"
    container_name: wiremock
    volumes:
        - ./wiremock/extensions:/var/wiremock/extensions
        - ./wiremock/__files:/home/wiremock/__files
        - ./wiremock/mappings:/home/wiremock/mappings
    entrypoint: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh", "--global-response-templating", "--disable-gzip", "--verbose"]

I have a request that contains a Date and I want to return the next 3 hours in the response
I can allready return a list of 3 nodes in the json response but I cant find a way to calculate the next 3 hours. Is this feasible?
Request
/nexthours?deliveryDateUtc=2024-05-20T10:00:00Z

Expected Response
{
   "next3hours":[
      {"position":"1","timestamp":"2024-05-20T10:00:00Z"},
      {"position":"2","timestamp":"2024-05-20T11:00:00Z",
      {"position":"3","timestamp":"2024-05-20T12:00:00Z"
   ]
}

file in mapping folder (nexthours.json)
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/nexthours"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200, 
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "bodyFileName": "nexthourstemplate.json",
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}

file in __files (nexthourstemplate.json)
{
  "next3hours": [
    {{#each (range 1 3)}}
    {
      "position": {{this}},
    "timestamp": "{{request.query.deliveryDateUtc}}"
    }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
    {{/each}}
  ]
}

This gives me
{
   "next3hours":[
      {"position":"1","timestamp":"2024-05-20T10:00:00Z"},
      {"position":"2","timestamp":"2024-05-20T10:00:00Z",
      {"position":"3","timestamp":"2024-05-20T10:00:00Z"
   ]
}

but I dont see a way to calculate the value for timestamp. Is this feasible?

The trick here is to parse the date and provide an offset.  Offsets can be things like 3 days or 1 years but in this case we can use the hours offset.
For your example, we will need to base the offset off of the range we are looping through.  Here is the updated version of your nexthourstemplate.json:
{
  "next3hours": [
    {{#each (range 1 3)}}
    {{#assign 'currentOffset'}}{{this}} hours{{/assign}}
    {
      "position": {{this}},
      "timestamp": "{{date (parseDate request.query.deliveryDateUtc) offset=(lookup currentOffset) }}"
    }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
    {{/each}}
  ]
}

As you can see, the first thing we do is construct the offset and assign it to the variable currentOffset.  We then use the date helper and the parseDate helper to parse the date passed as the query parameter using the offest we generated:
{{date (parseDate request.query.deliveryDateUtc) offset=(lookup currentOffset) }}

Using your original request of /nexthours?deliveryDateUtc=2024-05-20T10:00:00Z this should return the following json:
{
  "next3hours": [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "timestamp": "2024-05-20T11:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "timestamp": "2024-05-20T12:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "position": 3,
      "timestamp": "2024-05-20T13:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}


Its wiered that wiremock handlebars doesnt have a full fledged API but has the features I need. Usually its the other way round
